use mlflow.pyfunc.load_model with option not compile keras models
I would like to use the function mlflow.pyfunc.load_model.
Most of the models are keras models and unfortunately one of the model defines an own loss function.
How can I enable loading the model w/o compile for "predict" use only?
The option keras_model_kwargs={"compile": False} does not apply to pyfunc.load_model.
